# Scrappy Installation and Command Line

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, command-line, scrapy

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.4  versions installed on my MacOS. And i downloaded [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) with **pip** as suggested.

```
$pip install scrapy
```

It automatically installed required packages into 3.4 directory. Than i realized that [scrappy is not supporting Python3](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-work-with-python-3) currently. So i decided to change the installation directory and reinstalled scrapy with below command which is for Python2 spesific packages

```
$python2 -m pip install scrapy
```

After executing this command, scrapy is succesfully installed on my 2.7 directory. But whenever i try to execute a **scrapy** command it still refers to the version located at Python3/bin so it is not working.
As a workaround im using full path of the scrapy executable in Python2 directory and its working now.

How can i change the default option for `scrapy` command or any other commands so that the commandline understands which directory im talking about whether it is located on 2.7/bin or 3.4/bin directory.

**EDIT :** I uninstalled scrapy in python3 directory using `$pip3 uninstall scrapy` but still gives me below error when i type `scrapy`

-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/scrapy: No such file or directory

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just uninstall python3 scrapy via `pip3 uninstall scrapy`

Comment: thanks @Granitosaurus but it didnt work for me. See my edit

Comment: Try reinstalling scrapy on python2 now and it should solve the issue. `pip2 install scrapy  --force-reinstall`

Comment: I deleted all the versions of scrapy and reinstalled with pip2 install scrapy. But when i type scrapy it still refers to python3 directory. I think my problem is about Environmental Variables of python location @Granitosaurus

Comment: that is indeed the issue, however reinstalling scrapy should override the entry points. So there's definitely an issue somewhere there.

Comment: @Granitosaurus your solution was right. Restarting the terminal after reinstalling the scrapy solve path problem. Now scrapy command is working without path. Thanks. And if you write it as an aswer i will accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81984/discussion-between-mrgenco-and-granitosaurus).